# How to start multiple servers/processes in Rust and also close them on SIGINT/SIGTERM?

Tags: rust

This is my third day using Rust. I am developing a web-service in it. This is the pattern that I'm trying to implement:

The main Application struct:

```
/// Application is the main application struct.
struct Application {
    /// adapters is the list of various servers/processes that constitute the Application.
    adapters: Vec<Box<dyn IAdapter>>,
}

/// Application is the main application implementation.
impl Application {
    /// start method launches the Application by starting all the adapters.
    async fn start(&self) {}

    /// stop method stops the Application by stopping all the adapters.
    async fn stop(&self) {}
}
```

This is the Adapter trait:

```
/// IAdapter represents an Application process.
pub trait IAdapter {
    /// name provides the name of the Adapter.
    fn name(&self) -> String;
    /// start starts the adapter.
    fn start(&self) -> PinFuture<OptionBoxErr>;
    /// stop stops the adapter.
    fn stop(&self) -> PinFuture<OptionBoxErr>;
}
```

Here are the type aliases used in the Adapter trait:

```
/// PinFuture<T> is essentially Future<Output = T>
pub type PinFuture<T> = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = T>>>;

// OptionBoxErr is essentially Option<Error>
pub type OptionBoxErr = Option<Box<dyn Error>>;
```

Here, the `IAdapter` trait can be implemented by any process one may want to have in the Application, for instance: an HTTP server or a cron job manager.

Below are the things that I know I need to do, but can't due to Rust's strictness.

1. The `main` method calls the `start` method of the `Application` which in turn loops over all the `adapters` *concurrently* to call their `start` methods. This flow starts up the whole Application.
2. The `main` method, at some point, also sets up a listener for SIGINT/SIGTERM, to call the `stop` method of the `Application`, which then again loops over all the `adapters` *concurrently* to call their `stop` methods. This flow gracefully shuts down the whole Application.

Below is the ugliness that I've managed to do so far:

```
fn main() {
    let application = Application {
        adapters: vec![
            /* HTTP server */
            /* Cron Job Manager */
        ],
    };

    let application_stop_future = async {
        println!("Attaching signal listener.");
        let mut signals = signal_hook::iterator::Signals::new(&[SIGINT]).unwrap();
        signals.forever().next();

        println!("Shutting down the Application...");
        application.stop().await;
    //  ^^^^^^^^^^^ Does not live long enough.
    };

    let application_start_future_boxed = Box::pin(application.start());
    //                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^ Does not live long enough.
    let application_stop_future_boxed = Box::pin(application_stop_future);

    let futures_vec: Vec<PinFuture<()>> = vec![
        application_start_future_boxed,
        application_stop_future_boxed,
    ];

    // block_on blocks until the provided Future is resolved.
    futures::executor::block_on(future::select_all(futures_vec));
}
```

I *somewhat* understand why it doesn't work. But I have absolutely no idea what to do beyond this. Also, I have not even touched the part where the `Application.start` will concurrently call the `IAdapter.start` methods.

Counting on some help. By the way, I am proficient in Go, if you want to use its analogies.

Try not to pay much attention to the type-aliases I've created. I was just fighting the compiler to make things work.

Comment: Note that `select_all` will be resolved as soon as _one_ of the provided futures resolves. You probably want `join_all` instead.

Comment: @Jmb Great suggestion. However, the main compilation problem still stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't checked code to make sure this will work but changing adapters field type to `Arc<Vec<Box<dyn IAdapter>>>` and deriving clone for the struct should allow you to just clone the application object when inserting it into the application_stop_future therefore avoiding the "object moved" issues

Comment: If I clone the Adapters vector, won't I end up with two separate HTTP servers? (if the HTTP server is an adapter)

Comment: No. This is because Arc turns the field into a checked reference, so cloning the struct just clones the reference. Arc is required to make sure the object remains thread safe.

Comment: Sounds promising. I'll implement it in some time.

Comment: Ok cool, give this thread another post if you get stuck and I'll have a look:)

Comment: I followed your suggestion but made a few other changes.

In main, I created an "application" variable, then I made a clone of it in the next line.
I gave the ownership of the first one to the "async move" block which gives back the "application_stop_future" and used the second variable to call "application.start".

I also had to update the application's impl methods to accept "self" instead of "&self".
It all compiles now, but I hope I'm not violating any good practices?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - yes this should be fine, glad to see you've got things working!

Answer (score 0):

Your system architecture looks close to an "actor model".  I'd take a look at https://crates.io/crates/actix-web